# Avoid recompiling native code for each flavour in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with multiple flavors and some native code that remains the same for each flavor. The problem here is Gradle recompiles the native code when building the different flavors, how can I ensure the native code is build only once for all the flavors?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/423